# Iterate through multiple rows of dataframe and dropping rows based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe:

```
  column1
19:08:22
ABCD
19:08:40
WXYZ
AAAA
19:09:02
XXXX
ZZZZ
19:09:49
ABCD
```

I want to keep only those rows which has text value in two consecutive rows after a row containing time(dtype of this is also string).

I'm looking for this output:

```
  column1
19:08:40
WXYZ
AAAA
19:09:02
XXXX
ZZZZ
```

Or in a better way:

```
column1   text1  text2
19:08:40  WXYZ   AAAA
19:09:02  XXXX   ZZZZ
```

I'm not sure how to approach this problem,

I thought of using .shift(2) to compare the rows but it isn't working.
Also thought of running a iterative loop such as:

```
for index,rows in df.iterrows():
  current_row = rows
  ###Check for alternate row, if this contains time value remove them.
```

But this isn't a right way of attempting this problem. Any help or directions is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
grp = df['column1'].str.match('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}').cumsum()
m = df.groupby(grp)['column1'].transform('count') > 2
df.loc[m]
```

Output:

```
    column1
2  19:08:40
3      WXYZ
4      AAAA
5  19:09:02
6      XXXX
7      ZZZZ
```

Details:

- First create group by using regex to match pattern for "time", then
  cumsum to group or block records together.
- Next use groupby with transform to count the number of rows in each
  group
- Lastly, filter dataframe using boolean indexing based on the number
  of records in each gorup.

#### Update going further:

```
df['grp'] = df['column1'].str.match('\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}').cumsum()
m = df.groupby('grp')['column1'].transform('count') > 2
df_out = df.loc[m].copy()
df_out['time'] = df_out['column1'].str.extract('(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})').ffill()
df_out = df_out.query('column1 != time')
df_out.set_index(['time', df_out.groupby('time').cumcount()+1])['column1'].unstack().add_prefix('text')
```

Output:

```
         text1 text2
time                
19:08:40  WXYZ  AAAA
19:09:02  XXXX  ZZZZ
```

Comment: Hey, the solution works perfectly. Can you check the new edit that i'd made on my final df, is it possible to get in that format?

Comment: @ShubhamR Sure... I can probably make this a lot more efficient, but you started trying to fix your first problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the conditions and reconstruct a DataFrame,

```
cond1 = (df['column1'].str.contains('\d+')) & (df['column1'].shift(-1).str.contains('[A-Za-z]+')) & (df['column1'].shift(-2).str.contains('[A-Za-z]+')).fillna(False)

column1_idx = df[cond1].index
text1_idx = df[cond1].index+1
text2_idx = df[cond1].index+2

pd.DataFrame({'column1':df.iloc[column1_idx,0].reset_index(drop = True), 'text1':df.iloc[text1_idx,0].reset_index(drop = True),'text2':df.iloc[text2_idx,0].reset_index(drop = True)})
df[cond1]

    column1     text1   text2
0   19:08:40    WXYZ    AAAA
1   19:09:02    XXXX    ZZZZ
```